# Removing the Overhead of sending Xmlhttprequest when the the data already arrived in the first response

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, abort

I am building a random quotes generator and for this i am using Xmlhttprequest to get quotes from an API.
When someone clicks on the Generate quote button an http get request is sent to the Api and the random Quotes are getting displayed with every click. Everything is working fine for me but the only problem is that for every click i am sending a new http request and i want to send a request once and then continue displaying the response data. I have tried using abort() method here but still i m facing some issues.
can somone guide me how to achive it?

```
MY html files looks something like this
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app.css"> 
    <script src="assets/scripts/xmlhttprequest.js" defer></script>
    <!-- <script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script> -->

</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h2 id="heading">Random Quotes Generator</h2>
        <div id="quotes">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Generate Quotes</button>
            </div>
            <div>
               <article></article>
               <p id="authorName"></p>
    </div>
    
        
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>


CSS code

body{

    background-color:darkcyan;
}

#heading{

    font-style: oblique;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 60px;
   margin-top: 30px;
    
}
#quotes{

    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    
    
}
.inner{
    background-color:lightblue;
    border: 0px solid green;
    border-style:groove;
    padding:90px; /*--100*/
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    width:40%;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:saddlebrown;
}

#authorName{
    text-align:right;
    color: lightseagreen;
}


Javascript code -
const button=document.querySelector('button')
const innerQuotesDiv=document.querySelectorAll('div')[2]
const article=innerQuotesDiv.firstElementChild
const authorName=article.nextElementSibling
    
function generateRandomIndex(length){

    console.log(length)
    return (Math.floor(Math.random()*length))
  }

  function getQuotes(){
    
   // console.log(noOfTimesBtnClicked)
    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('GET','https://type.fit/api/quotes')
    xhr.onload=function(){

      let quotes=JSON.parse(xhr.response)
        console.log(quotes)
        let index=generateRandomIndex(quotes.length)
        innerQuotesDiv.classList.add('inner')
        article.textContent=quotes[index].text 
        if(!quotes[index].author)
       {
           authorName.textContent='Anonymous'  
       }
       else{
        authorName.textContent=quotes[index].author  
       }
    }
    
    xhr.onerror=function(){

      console.log(xhr.response)
      console.log(xhr.status)
      alert('something went wrong')
  }
  xhr.send() 
  
  }

  function abortGetRequest(xhr){
    
    xhr.abort()
  }



  button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    //console.log('clicked')
    


    getQuotes()

    

})


JS code in which i have tried to use abort() --


const button=document.querySelector('button')
const innerQuotesDiv=document.querySelectorAll('div')[2]
const article=innerQuotesDiv.firstElementChild
const authorName=article.nextElementSibling


function generateRandomIndex(length){

    console.log(length)
    return (Math.floor(Math.random()*length))
  }

  function getQuotes(){
    
   // console.log(noOfTimesBtnClicked)
    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('GET','https://type.fit/api/quotes')
    xhr.onload=function(){

      let quotes=JSON.parse(xhr.response)
        console.log(quotes)
        let index=generateRandomIndex(quotes.length)
        innerQuotesDiv.classList.add('inner')
        article.textContent=quotes[index].text 
        if(!quotes[index].author)
       {
           authorName.textContent='Anonymous'  
       }
       else{
        authorName.textContent=quotes[index].author  
       }
    }
    
    xhr.onerror=function(){

      console.log(xhr.response)
      console.log(xhr.status)
      alert('something went wrong')
  }
  xhr.send() 
  abortGetRequest(xhr)

  }

  function abortGetRequest(xhr){
    
    xhr.abort()
  }

function displayQuotes(quotes){

  let index=generateRandomIndex(quotes.length)
  innerQuotesDiv.classList.add('inner')
  article.textContent=quotes[index].text 
  if(!quotes[index].author)
 {
     authorName.textContent='Anonymous'  
 }
 else{
  authorName.textContent=quotes[index].author  
 }

}

  button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    //console.log('clicked')
    


    getQuotes()

   
    

})
```

Using fetch API -I am getting undefined in quotes i think its because the quotes executes before the onload function. how i can do it synchronoulsy or there is any other way i can use the data coming from that promise assigned to the quote variable.

```
const button=document.querySelector('button')
const innerQuotesDiv=document.querySelectorAll('div')[2]
const article=innerQuotesDiv.firstElementChild
const authorName=article.nextElementSibling
let quotes;
// console.log(button)
// console.dir(innerQuotesDiv)
 //console.log(article)
 //console.log(authorName)

 quotes=window.addEventListener('load',fetchApi)
function generateRandomIndex(length){

  console.log(length)
  return (Math.floor(Math.random()*length))
}

function fetchApi(){

   let d=fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes')
    .then(response=>{
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(data)
        return data
    })
    console.log(d)
    return d
}




function changeQuotes(){
     
    console.log(quotes)
    let index=generateRandomIndex(quotes.length)
    innerQuotesDiv.classList.add('inner')
    article.textContent=quotes[index].text 
    if(!quotes[index].author)
   {
       authorName.textContent='Anonymous'  
   }
   else{
    authorName.textContent=quotes[index].author  
   }

}
  button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
      
         changeQuotes()
  })
```

Comment: What are those “some issues”? [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212). Why does the button click fetch the quotes? Why not simply fetch them once at page load?

Comment: the issue is like either there is no result at all or only one quote is displayed after clicking again on the button nothing happens.i will try fetching it on page load.

Comment: hi i have done it with on load and it is working fine. how i can do it with using fetch api?
i have included the fetch api code too. i don't have any idea how to do it using fetch api. you can see the code for fetch api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this, but...

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    const innerQuotesDiv=document.querySelectorAll('div')[2]
    const article=innerQuotesDiv.firstElementChild
    const authorName=article.nextElementSibling

    function changeQuotes(quotes) {
        console.log(quotes)
        let index = generateRandomIndex(quotes.length)
        innerQuotesDiv.classList.add('inner')
        article.textContent = quotes[index].text
        if (!quotes[index].author) {
            authorName.textContent = 'Anonymous'
        } else {
            authorName.textContent = quotes[index].author
        }
    }

    const request= fetchData('https://type.fit/api/quotes');

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',()=>{
           request.then(changeQuotes);
    })
})

function generateRandomIndex(length){
    console.log(length)
    return (Math.floor(Math.random()*length))
}

function fetchData(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            return data
        })
}
```

Comment: but can you explain me how this piece of code is working document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',()=>{
           request.then(changeQuotes);
    })

Comment: We simply make a request and when the button is clicked, we add a new `then` chain with changeQuotes handler to the request promise, which can be called immediately if the request promise has already been processed with the requested data, or later when the request is ready. This expression is shorthand for request.then ((quotes) => changeQuotes (quotes));